# Set limits in histogram for xaxis including 0 values

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, limits

This is my subsetted data, of which I plot a histogram with highlighted 0 values and draw a normal distribution:

```
values <- c(25.222222, 6.000000, 2.057143, 0.000000, 2.142857, 0.000000, 73.666667, 4.081081, 43.133333, 18.937500, 60.822222, 23.379310, 54.954412, 8.492308, 67.646250, 15.885000, 38.585859, 46.810606, 31.565152, 39.813889, 40.620000, 25.958000, 54.821429, 9.000000, 33.040476, 50.329670, 43.525641, 33.508696, 34.265385, 57.003544, 36.690434, 48.074074, 70.372222, 77.602564, 29.997436, 71.739683, 11.320000, 2.938776, 10.101562, 35.037956)

df <- data.frame(variable = "TH_part", value=values)

ggplot(df, aes(value)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(fill = value==0), colour = "black", binwidth = 10, position="stack") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 140, by = 20)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    stat_function(fun=function(value, mean, sd) 10*nrow(df)*dnorm(value, mean, sd), 
                  args=fitdistr(df$value, "normal")$estimate)
```

[image: normal xaxis]

However, I would like to extend the xaxis to 140 to have the same scale as in another histogram with more data. Unfortunately my code drops the 0 values:

```
ggplot(df, aes(value)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(fill = value==0), colour = "black", binwidth = 10, position="stack") + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 140, by = 20), limits = c(0,140)) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    stat_function(fun=function(value, mean, sd) 10*nrow(df)*dnorm(value, mean, sd), 
                  args=fitdistr(df$value, "normal")$estimate)
```

[image: drops 0 values]

I don't understand, because 0 is still in the range of my limits. Is there another statement to control for the xaxis?

Comment: maybe set limits to `c(NA, 140)`

Comment: yes, indeed! easy solution, thank you.